Could a wingsuit using fans be made with our current technology?
Like the MCU's Vulture, could we create a wingsuit utilizing bladed fans for flight? Elsewhere I've looked says it's a problem with the power source, but if that were taken care of, could the rest of the design follow suit? Or is it also a problem with the materials?
I'm working on a novel that uses a similar concept, but I always like to add a touch of realism to my writing, so is this realistically feasible?

It's your fictional world, you can decide what is and isn't feasible in it. You seem to have decided that it will exist, so what exactly are you asking us about?

Eliding the power source is kind of a big handwave.  You could do a lot of things if you had a battery with arbitrarily high power density.

@sphennings that could be a blanket statement for this forum. The OP has decided to put them in, but only wants to know how much they need to bend the rules besides the power problem.

Whether or not something can exist in the Real World has become the bane of [worldbuilding.se]'s existence - much like the story identification trend on [scifi.se]. I agree with @sphennings, per the [help/on-topic], we answer questions about imaginary worlds. The Real World is already built, which makes this nothing more than an engineering/materials science question. What makes an [tag:alternate-earth] Q on-topic is that something is actually different about the Real World such that we're not longer in it. I, for one, detest that we've become Physics-Lite. VTC:Not About Worldbuilding.

@JBH The problem with Worldbuilding.SE not being a Physics-lite.SE is that it would become a Redundant-Writing.SE instead.

@Rekesoft the question could be valid if OP asked a more specific version of it. Is there a single thing OP has concerns about they could ask about that. I'd contend that asking "Is there something about x that would prevent it from being used in a wingsuit, or do I need to handwave or make up some technobabble?" would be an appropriately scoped question for this site as opposed to asking more broadly what is possible in the real world once you have already decided that your world has wingsuits.

@sphennings My thing is that, although I plan for there to be elements unrealistic to the real world, where possible, I like to make the more mechanical or scientific aspects as real as possible. It's sort of my attempt at saying "this is what's possible with what we have right now or what we will have soon." If it's a materials problem, it's more like "could we power it now if we made it light enough?" If necessary, I can handwave it, but I personally would prefer not to.

@Rekesoft [Writing.se] would instantly close this question. [Writing.se] focuses on the skill of writing, not the contents of a story. The problem with Worldbuilding becoming Physics-lite is that it loses all of the whimsy of building worlds. There's no "what if?" Only "can it be done per science as we know it today?" That we never what this site was expected to be (and there was a time when it wasn't that way).

If you write a good story most people won't care if elements of your world are impossible in the real world. You don't need to tell your readers about the material properties of your wingsuit. Ask yourself why you feel the need to have those details. If you are choosing to ignore practicality, opportunity cost, manufacturability, etc... why do you care if you need to handwave or not. Using words like advanced composites, alloys, and engines covers a multitude of sins just as well as if you decided to name drop real world materials. Next time ask about something more specific than is it viable.

@JBH So, you'd like it to be InternalCoherence.SE? I like a What-If question as much as the next guy, but they have their own set of problems. For starters, there's considerable overlap between the best "what if" questions and the "too broad/too story based" questions. The kind of questions you like most are inherently speculative, which a much harder way to choose the "right" answer, and the askers always want a 'yes'. My own most-voted answer on this site is a 'No' answer with nearly 4 times more votes than the 'Yes' answer the OP picked anyway. Are you sure you want it that way?

@Rekesoft The questions I like most are those questions that are trying to build a world that's internally consistent. The questions I like least are questions that could be just as easily (and often more effectively) be asked on another stack. Frame challenges are a long-standing tradition here and are useful to the OP (if they're looking to actually understand their issue) and it's not uncommon for a good frame challenge to be well voted. Frankly, I'm also not a fan of open-ended speculative questions. I'm very much a fan of questions that follow the rules of the [tour] and [help].

Yes and No
The problem, as it stands, is due to two factors:

In order to make the system strong enough to perform the functions, even with the use of exotic materials, it has to have a minimum weight.
In order to shift that minimum weight, you need more power than can realistically be generated.

Adding more fuel adds more weight, adding a bigger engine adds more weight etc.
Now - there are 'jet packs' that have been designed and tested and flown, but they are of limited use because of the above problem.
To answer your world building question - if Power Source is not an issue, then it doesn't really matter what material you use, you could create a concrete aircraft with a sufficiently powerful engine (Not that I would recommend that...)
If materials is not an issue, then any current engine and power source should be sufficient.
The challenge with modern day tech is that for the weight of materials we need to make it safe and practical, we don't have a power source that can provide the output for long enough to make it a realistic travel option.

Google says yes:  https://www.m2ktechnologies.com/martinjetpack.php MARTIN JETPACK

They call it a Jetpack but it is a gasoline engine driving twin ducted fans
Your biggest obstacle is a power source. Making it small enough, and power/weight efficient.

this does not really answer the question, thats like saying yes because helicopters exist.

@John This is a real world analog of the MCU's Vulture OP referenced to compare his idea to.  How is this not a valid answer to if it would be possible to build with current tech?
Also... not to john but, most probably the down votes are reactions to my comments above That keep being deleted without notice.
